# Proper way to write an 'If it doesn't work, fix it and try again' function in Ruby

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, accessor, rescue

I have an accessor object which is unavoidably intermittent. Sometimes when it tries an action, its internals crash and need to be restarted before the action is reattempted.

It's easy enough to write a function like:

```
def might_break
    try_something_that_might_break
rescue
    fix_it
    might_break
end
```

With a counter to avoid infinite breakage, of course.

But I'd like to keep things DRY, and every one of my accessors methods need pretty much the same care.

I thought about making a function `safely` which takes a block, but then I'm not sure how I could have it return to the parent function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see `retry` http://rubyquicktips.com/post/1122838559/redo-vs-retry

Comment: can u share some details about accessor object, a sample code may be, so that people can get better idea of problem>

Comment: A better question is, why are its internals sometimes broken and why does it crash? That sounds like poorly written code and you're trying to apply a bandage to something that's got arterial bleeding. Granted, `rescue` can help, but understanding and fixing the root cause is the correct solution.

Comment: It doesn't crash often, but when it does it's out of my control. I'm scraping information from a server which I do not own or have administrative access to. Sometimes my session breaks off. It happens infrequently enough that I just need to put a bandaid on it, and extreme hacks might do more damage than good at my level :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
def safely num, &block
  count = 0
  begin
    block.call
  rescue
    count += 1
    retry if count < num
  end
end
```

Call it with `safely(5) {your_broken_method}`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much.